# Ionic 4 - how to create SCSS custom mixins

Tags: ionic-framework, sass

I've created a custom mixin this way:

```
@mixin donut-chart($name, $perc, $size, $width, $base, $center, $color, $textColor: $color, $textSize: 40px) {

  $color2: $color;
  $base2: $base;
  $deg: ($perc/100*360)+deg;
  $deg1: 90deg;
  $deg2: $deg;

  @if $perc < 50 {
    $base: $color;
    $color: $base2;
    $color2: $base2;
    $deg1: ($perc/100*360+90)+deg;
    $deg2: 0deg;
  }

  .donut-chart {
    &#{$name} {
      width: $size;
      height: $size;
      background: $base;

      .slice {
        &.one {
          clip: rect(0 $size $size/2 0);
          -webkit-transform: rotate($deg1);
          transform: rotate($deg1);
          background: $color;
        }

        &.two {
          clip: rect(0 $size/2 $size 0);
          -webkit-transform: rotate($deg2);
          transform: rotate($deg2);
          background: $color2;
        }
      }

      .chart-center {
        top: $width;
        left: $width;
        width: $size - ($width * 2);
        height: $size - ($width * 2);
        background: $center;

        span {
          font-size: $textSize;
          line-height: $size - ($width * 2);
          color: $textColor;
          &:after {
            content: '#{$perc}%';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

It works fine this way:

```
@include donut-chart('.chart1', 75, 70px, 5px, #CCC, #999, #666, #333, 10);
```

So it ONLY works if I put the mixin at the same SCSS file as the `@include`.

Is there any way to put the mixin in an external file so I can re-use it in many places?

I tried with `@import` in theme folder, variables.scss file and globals.scss file, but it always shows this error:

```
[ng] @include donut-chart('.chart1', 75, 70px, 5px, #CCC, #999, #666, #333, 10);
[ng]         ^
[ng]       No mixin named donut-chart
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to import the file the mixin is in into the file in which you're calling it via `@include`.

So, something like...

```
@import "../mixins/donut-chart.scss";

@include donut-chart('.chart1', 75, 70px, 5px, #CCC, #999, #666, #333, 10);
```